# Ajax use on website design

Tags: ajax, performance

I just want to ask for your experience. I'm designing a public website, using jQuery Ajax in most of operations. I'm having some timeouts, and I think it should be for hosting provider cause. Any of you have expirience in this case and may advise me on some hints (especially on timeouts handling)?

Thanks in advance to all.

Esteve

Comment: What do you mean by timeouts? If the browser times out loading a page, then you need to check your internet connection or switch host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a half-decent host, chances are these aren't network timeouts but are rather due to insufficient hardware which causes your server-side scripts to take too long to answer. For example if you have an autocomplete field and the script goes through a database of 100,000 entries, this is a breeze for newer servers but older "budget" servers or overcrowded shared hosting servers might croak on it.

Depending on what your Ajax operations are, you may be able to break them down in shorter chunks. If you're doing database queries for example, use LIMIT and OFFSET and only return say, 5 entries at a time. When those 5 entries arrive on the client, make another Ajax call for 5 more, so from the user's point of view the entries will keep coming in and it will look fluid (instead of waiting 30s and possibly timing out before they see all entries at once). If you do this make sure you display a spiffy web 2.0 turning wheel to let the user know if they should be waiting some more or if it's done.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tekahera. I just wanted to confirm the aspects you explain: hosting provider hardware requirements, optimization of sql queries, ... Good advices ;)

Comment: In fact, it really seems its a hosting provider fault for bad hardware. I think Ajax it's a good tool for designing more handy websites.